# Crop all bounding boxes from training and testing data after tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have trained tensorflow object detection API for text detection on google colaboratory. Using this code:

```
#run detector on test image
#it takes a little longer on the first run and then runs at normal speed. 
import random

TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = glob.glob('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Final_datasets/UTiV/test/*.jpg')
image_path = random.choice(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)

# Things to try:
# Flip horizontally
# image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

# Convert image to grayscale
# image_np = np.tile(
#     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(
np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
  image_np_with_detections,
  detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
  (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
  detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
  category_index,
  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
  max_boxes_to_draw=200,
  min_score_thresh=.5,
  agnostic_mode=False,
  )

 plt.figure(figsize=(12,16))
 plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, I want to crop these bounding boxes.

```
width=600
height=900

ymin = int((boxes[0][0][0]*height))
xmin = int((boxes[0][0][1]*width))
ymax = int((boxes[0][0][2]*height))
xmax = int((boxes[0][0][3]*width))

Result = np.array(img_np[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax])
```

But it says:

```
NameError: name 'boxes' is not defined
```

Any help would bee highly appreciated.

Comment: The variable`boxes` is not defined anywhere in the code above. If it is supposed to be the output if any function, make sure that happens before trying to use the variable in subsequent analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is, to extract bounding boxes from this list `detections['detection_boxes'][0]`.

A better solution for extracting the bounding boxes would be to access `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` function which you can find in `object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py`. It already has post process version of `detections['detection_boxes'][0]` before visualizing them on the image through using `draw_bounding_box_on_image()`. You can return them from there in a list and access it here.